# Spree product is missing name in structured data

Tags: spree

Google's Webmasters Tools show me an error telling me that my product's structured data is missing the name value. However when I view source on my product page I can see that the name is definitely there. I see this:

```
<h1 class="product-title" itemprop="name">
```

Why doesn't Google see this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual page and code, it's difficult to determine exactly why you're seeing that error message.  But I would guess that it's because of improper nesting.  So just make sure that the name property is nested within the product type.

Comment: You're right that's the problem. The Spree Fancy theme from the Spree folks breaks the nesting. Seems a pretty [common problem](http://devblog.shopjoy.com.au/2014/06/your-spree-storefronts-schemaorg.html)